# React redux correct state update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a question is this code correct? State in React is inmutable so this is correct or not?

```
 case "GET_SINGLE":
      const newState = [...state.data];
      const id = action.payload;
     
      const item = newState.filter((item) => item.id === id.id);
   
      return {
        ...state,
        record: item[0],
      };
```

Comment: Probably it's enough to use `state.data.filter()` only. See from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): *The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state has a property `data` with an array of objects and a property `record` with the current object.  If you are looking on opinions of the state structure, I think this is an unnecessary duplication.  You could just save the id of the current record and use a selector to get the whole object.  It's not good to have the same data in multiple places because you want a single source of truth.

But as far as this selector is concerned, you are finding the item which matches the `id` from the `action.payload` and saving it the the property `record`.  You are only looking for one item so you should use `find()` instead of `filter()`.

Using the variable `id.id` is very confusing.  You can use destructuring to get just the `id` from the payload (`const {id} = action.payload;`).  Or you could just use `action.payload.id` in your comparison (`item.id === action.playload.id`).

```
 case "GET_SINGLE":
      const {id} = action.payload;
     
      const item = state.data.find((item) => item.id === id);
   
      return {
        ...state,
        record: item,
      };
```